# automatically open website in my browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

When I start my browser Chrome and Firefox, the website named "http://www.bilexlahntu.ru" opens automatically. Also there are no extensions installed on it. How to solve this problem? Also sometimes Chrome shows a pop-up to download something.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: try cleaning your pc with  [Hitman Pro](http://www.surfright.nl) , then install an antimalware (e.g [AVG](http://www.avg.com/) )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your browser contains adware. Use some addware remover. For automatically opening sites, have checked chrome>>settings>>on start up and remove or change the start up pages. I have used addblock extension for chrome.. link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

Comment: there is nothing on the start up bro. i choose the option continue where you left. but when i open the browser automatically open this site "http://www.bilexlahntu.ru".

Comment: pop up download dialog box of idm should be related to idm settings. I think you should remove allow access to file url in idm extension. chrome>> more tools>>extension>>uncheck allow access to file url in idm extension.

Comment: for addware problem, visit  https://forums.techguy.org/threads/how-to-stop-websites-from-opening-automatically-in-browser.1127423/#post8920811

Comment: i find the solution, after uninstalling all the application that are from unknown publisher, i don't face this problem and all my browser works well as earlier

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution, after uninstalling all the application that are from unknown publisher, i don't face this problem and all my browser works well as earlier.